# How can I use Abs while plotting?

Tags: plotting

Equations:

```
[x]'{t} == -g1 ι - ι (Δ1 - (γ ι/2 - J^2/(Δ2 - (γ ι)/2)) x[t] + (J^2 ι y[t])/(Δ2 - (γ ι)/2),

[y]'{t} == -g2 ι + (J^2 ι x[t])/(Δ2 - (γ ι)/ 2) - ι (Δ1 - (γ ι)/2 - J^2/(Δ2 - (γ ι)/2)) y[t],
```

Solution:

```
sol = DSolve[system, {x, y}, t],
```

For plot:

```
{xs[t_, Δ1_, Δ2_, ι_, m_, n_, γ_, J_, g1_, g2_],  ys[t_, Δ1_, Δ2_, ι_, m_,n_, γ_, J_, g1_, g2_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. First@sol /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> b};
```

If I use `Abs` outside the `Evaluate`, I am getting only one common color i.e. last color for all lines using `PlotStyle{colors}`.

```
Plot[Abs[Evaluate[{xs[u], ys[u]} /. u -> Sequence[t, 1, 3, √-1, 1, 0, 0.1, 3, 0.1, 0.1]]], {t,0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}].
```

However, if I use `Abs` after `Evaluate`, I am getting different color with `PlotStyle{colors}`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Abs[{xs[u], ys[u]} /.u -> Sequence[t, 1, 3, √-1, 1, 0, 0.1, 3, 0.1, 0.1]]], {t,0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

How can I get the desired color while using `Abs` before `Evaluate` line?

Comment: Why don't you show a [minimal workin example (mwe)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) that illustrates your problem? See [here](http://sscce.org/) for general guidelines.

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and to post a minimal working example. But as far as I can interpret your question, the problem is not the function `Abs` but the table / list you might be using within `Plot`. Check these expressions (1) `Plot[Table[x^n, {n, 0, 2}], {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]` and (2) `Plot[Evaluate@Table[x^n, {n, 0, 2}], {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]`. In (1) you will get the same behavior as in your problem, in (2) the functions are plotted in the colors you wanted.